# Dynamically reset ng-form in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have taken a look at the following: [Reset Form in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372791/reset-form-in-angularjs) and [Angular clear subform data and reset validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648427/angular-clear-subform-data-and-reset-validation) from these I am trying to create a dynamic form reset/clear function which would look like something like the following:

```
$scope.clearSection = function(formName){

    $scope.formName.$setPristine();
    $scope.formName.$setUntouched();
};
```

Is it possible to create a dynamic clear function like this in angular where the form name is dynamically passed to this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lnGym0vKsANL6oks30RG

```
$scope.resetForm = function(formName) {
  var form = $scope[formName];
  form.$setUntouched();
  form.$setPristine();
}
```

Note: You still need to reset the input values!

According to the docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

> **$setPristine();**
>   Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the
>   form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also
>   propagate to all the controls contained in this form.
>
> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want
>   to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.
>
> **$setUntouched()**; Sets the form to its untouched state.
>
> This method can be called to remove the 'ng-touched' class and set the
>   form controls to their untouched state (ng-untouched class).
>
> Setting a form controls back to their untouched state is often useful
>   when setting the form back to its pristine state.

$setPristine and $setUntouched only change the classes of the form controls, not the values. That means you still need to reset the values.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the resetting I realized that after posting the question. Just a quick extra question. Is it possible for me to just reset the object as linked in my question. aka object: {manythingshere: "asdasda"} to object: {} will this remove/reset the validation?

Comment: Yes it is, just reset the object to {}. Example plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/cGgnbtwnc47BHnFGB3QA

Comment: Marked this as the accepted answer because of the "in-depth" explanation  as well as a link to the docs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why not.

```
$scope.clearSection = function(formName){
    var frm = $scope[formName];
    frm.$setPristine();
    frm.$setUntouched();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well yes.

In JavaScript you can access variables of an object using the `[]` notation. Take the following example

```
var str = 'hello';
var obj = { hello: 'a' };
console.info(obj[str]); // outputs 'a'
```

so if formName is a string, you can simply get the property of the scope using

```
var form = $scope[formName]
```